# How to print dashed or dotted lines of css in pdf?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a webpage using HTML and CSS but when I'm trying to print the page the dotted lines become straight.

**CSS**

```
.box-heading {
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-top:.5pt dotted black;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom:.5pt dotted black;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}
```

When I am printing the dotted line become straight.

Comment: Do you see straight line in preview too? If not - fix your printer or write border size in pixels

Comment: you need to add in style inline instead of css class

Comment: I tried to recreate the issue with the given code but I'm not getting the straight line in print review.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the issue is in your print settings.

The ideal page size for a webpage is A4.

If you use any other size it will modify the original pixels and this may be the reason you are getting a straight line instead of a dotted line.

[image: Page size A4 - dotted line]

[image: Page size A3 - straight line]

Comment: I am using html2pdf library

Comment: @KumarShivam That information changes _a lot_ of cases. It's possible that html2pdf renders HTML wrong

Comment: @KumarShivam In that case, try to use Relative length units.